# esm does not resolve module-alias

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

So I'm using the package `esm` and `module-alias`, but it seems like esm does not register module-alias's paths.

Here's how I'm loading my server file:

```
nodemon -r esm ./src/index.js 8081
```

Here's the top of my `index.js` file:

```
import "module-alias/register"
import "@/setup"
```

`import "@/setup"` does not work whereas `require("@/setup")` does.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that `esm` tries to handle all `import` statements when parsing the file, before any other module gets loaded.

When processing `import` statements, it uses node's builtin `require` rather than the modified `require` created by `module-alias`

To fix this, you need to first load `module-alias` and then `esm`. This way, `module-alias` will get the chance to modify the `require` function before `esm` gets to do anything.

You can achive this by passing multiple `-r` parameters to node, but make sure `module-alias` comes first:

```
node -r module-alias/register -r esm index.js 8081
```

or with `nodemon`:

```
nodemon -r module-alias/register -r esm ./src/index.js 8081
```

You also need to remove the `import "module-alias/register"` from your code, since now it's loaded from the command line.

Comment: i need to add `node_modules`, like this `nodemon -r node_modules/module-alias/register`

Comment: I inverted the order and seems to be working now, mine is this: `node -r esm -r module-alias/register index.js`, The normal require wasn't working

Comment: confim, working order for me: `-r esm -r module-alias/register index.js`

Comment: For me that worked

Added "@std/esm": "cjs" to package.json
nodemon -r @std/esm -r module-alias/register ./app/server.mjs

Comment: What if I want to add my aliases manually, let's say with something like: `import * as path from 'path';
import * as moduleAlias from 'module-alias';
moduleAlias.addAlias('@', path.join(process.cwd(), 'dist', 'server'));` ?

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution, initially found in [this comment](https://github.com/ilearnio/module-alias/issues/59) to solve the problem without even using module-alias.

I also made a repo to simplify this, check it here [esm-module-alias](https://github.com/euberdeveloper/esm-module-alias)

Answer (score 0):

For me worked the following code:

## package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "pkill -f lib/serverIndex.js; NODE_ENV=development node lib/serverIndex.js",
```

## lib/serverIndex.js

```
require = require('esm')(module/*, options*/);
require('module-alias/register');
module.exports = require("./server.js");
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been plaguing me for years because I want to write good quality code that is shared between node & browser.
I finally found a system that works:

- Place 'nesm.js' in the root of your project
- [optional] Place the 'nesm' shell script in your path, make it executable
- Run scripts with: '**nesm file_to_run.js**' or '**node path/to/nesm.js -- file_to_run.js**'

**'nesm.js'**

```
/*
 * esm and module-alias do not play nicely together.
 * this precise arrangement is the only way I found to make it work.
 * you can run this from anywhere in your project hierarchy.
 * you can use args, and use in npm scripts.
 * encourage the node.js devs to make this work natively.  ux matters.
 * ---- CAVEATS
 * will not work with "type":"module"
 * ---- SETUP
 * place 'nesm.js' in the root of your project
 * [optional] place the 'nesm' shell script in your path, make it executable
 * ---- USAGE
 * > nesm file_to_run.js
 * to run without the nesm shell script:
 * > node path/to/nesm.js -- file_to_run.js
 * to run with nodemon:
 * > nodemon -- path/to/nesm.js -- file_to_run.js
*/
require = require('esm')(module);   // eslint-disable-line no-global-assign
require('module-alias/register');   // must come after esm for some reason

let runNext;
for(const arg of process.argv) {
    if(runNext) {
        let filename = arg;
        if(filename[0]!='.' && filename[0]!='/') filename = './'+filename;
        require(filename);
        break;
    }
    runNext = (arg=='--');
}
```

**'nesm' shell script**

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z $1 ]; then
    echo "Node esm runner.  Usage: nesm file_to_run.js"
    exit 1
fi
baseDir=$( pwd )
while [ ! -f "$baseDir/nesm.js" ]; do
    if [ ${#baseDir} -le 1 ]; then
        echo "nesm.js not found in folder ancestry"
        exit 1
    fi
    baseDir="$(dirname "$baseDir")"
done
file1=$(realpath $1);
node $baseDir/nesm.js -- $file1
```